# How do i import modules into classes when they are instantiated in python?

Tags: python, class, import, module

I have a class "ClassX". In it are multiple function definitions, each of which use the same module in different ways. Let's say that the module being imported is "ModuleY". When i instantiate this class, how do i make it import this module in a way that can be accessed by all of ClassX's functions?
I.e would i import it like this:

```
class ClassX():
   def __init__(self):
      import ModuleY
```

Like this:

```
class ClassX():
   import ModuleY
   def __init(self):
      #do something
```

or would i have to import the module for every function call:

```
class ClassX():
   def __init__(self):
      #do something#
   def functionA(self):
      import ModuleY
      #do something
   def functionB(self):
      import ModuleY
      #do something
```

Comment: why are you importing inside the class and not at the top of your script? but keep in mind the function scope is just that, it lasts the lifetime of the function.

Answer (score -1):

Just import ModuleY as normal and then refer to the functions within ModuleY as necessary in other parts of your script.

```
ModuleY.py

def do_something():
    print("something")


main.py 

import ModuleY

class ClassX():
    def __init__(self):
      # do_something()
      # prints "something"
```